# EF code first many to many with payload, compound key or surrogate key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design

I want to accomplish the following model: [image]

My code looks as follows (removed properties not relevant to the question):

```
public class Stock
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<StockProperty> StockProperties { get; set; }
}

public class StockProperty
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    public IList<StockPropertyValue> Values { get; set; }

    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }

}

public class StockPropertyValue
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}

public class Property
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StockProperty> StockProperties  { get; set; }
}
```

With this code I get two foreign keys in my StockPropertyValues table, Stock_Id and Property_Id. I could add an explicit primary key to StockProperty instead, which would give me a foreign key of StockPropertyId in the StockPropertyValues table. StockProperties does have some additional data of it's own. What would be the pros / cons of these different configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you showed here has the advantage that you will have a unique constraint on any combination of StockId and PropertyId out of the box. Using a single primary key for the StockProperties you have to configure a unique constraint yourself.On the downside, if you need explicit access to the foreign keys in StockPropertyValues you need annotations or the fluent API. Moreover, I found that some tools that will create an automatic UI for your tables (LightSwitch for instance, but this may have changed by now) cannot handle composite foreign keys.